# Have: patched kernel source, want: upstream commit hash

Tags: linux-kernel

A hardware company distributes its software platform as a tarball containing, among other things, a kernel source tree with no .git directory. I know the version and I know what `uname -a` outputs.

Is there any feasible way to find the closest upstream commit, i.e. the commit minimizing

```
diff -r linux/ /path/to/tarballed-linux/ | wc -l
```

or do I have to resort to iterating the above command over some reasonable range?

Comment: So did the company backports on this tree?

Comment: Possibly. Likely.

Answer (score 0):

If they didn't overwrite `Makefile` you can use `VERSION`,
`PATCHLEVEL` and `SUBLEVEL` to get a specific tag in `git` history.  For example, if it says:

```
VERSION = 4
PATCHLEVEL = 4
SUBLEVEL = 38
EXTRAVERSION =
NAME = Blurry Fish Butt
```

you can get a `v4.4.38` tag:

```
$ git show v4.4.38
tag v4.4.38
Tagger: Greg Kroah-Hartman <gregkh@linuxfoundation.org>
Date:   Sat Dec 10 19:08:14 2016 +0100

This is the 4.4.38 stable release
(...)
commit c95b7f1fab0c76882764a5196119237c8ad436ee
Author: Greg Kroah-Hartman <gregkh@linuxfoundation.org>
Date:   Sat Dec 10 19:08:05 2016 +0100

    Linux 4.4.38

diff --git a/Makefile b/Makefile
index b57ec79..6876efe 100644
--- a/Makefile
+++ b/Makefile
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
 VERSION = 4
 PATCHLEVEL = 4
-SUBLEVEL = 37
+SUBLEVEL = 38
 EXTRAVERSION =
 NAME = Blurry Fish Butt
```

However, note that there were 17 commits between `4.4.38` and `4.4.39`:

```
a34f0e8 (tag: v4.4.39) Linux 4.4.39
5d488de crypto: rsa - Add Makefile dependencies to fix parallel builds
1c0f4e0 hotplug: Make register and unregister notifier API symmetric
537e42d batman-adv: Check for alloc errors when preparing TT local data
f03531d m68k: Fix ndelay() macro
55e15b2 arm64: futex.h: Add missing PAN toggling
e29949e can: peak: fix bad memory access and free sequence
083021b can: raw: raw_setsockopt: limit number of can_filter that can be set
9a3baed crypto: mcryptd - Check mcryptd algorithm compatibility
c4db8a7 perf/x86: Fix full width counter, counter overflow
c6a5bf4 locking/rtmutex: Use READ_ONCE() in rt_mutex_owner()
b27d914 locking/rtmutex: Prevent dequeue vs. unlock race
e286b6c zram: restrict add/remove attributes to root only
a0bd6aa parisc: Fix TLB related boot crash on SMP machines
605f315 parisc: Remove unnecessary TLB purges from flush_dcache_page_asm and flush_icache_page_asm
db95986 parisc: Purge TLB before setting PTE
4bcea47 powerpc/eeh: Fix deadlock when PE frozen state can't be cleared
c95b7f1 (tag: v4.4.38) Linux 4.4.38
```

Comment: They didn't overwrite it. I have the alleged subversion. But I think it's heavily patched from this, as the diff line count is ENORMOUS. I'd like to traverse the commit tree starting at the "alleged" commit and find a minimizer.

Comment: Subversion? Linux world uses `git`.

Comment: sub-version. As in major + minor version.

Comment: Is this diff still enormous after checkouting the respective tag?

Comment: Well yes, otherwise I wouldn't have a problem.